# How do I fix TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Error

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, error-handling, typeerror

I've been searching in other questions, but I found no help. 
I got this code:

```
def pairs(self, listOrString):
        if listOrString:
            return filter(re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text)).match, frozenset(self.text))
        else:
            return ' '.join(filter(re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text)).match, frozenset(self.text)))

def pairs_freqency(self):
    return Counter(self.pairs(True))

def sum_pairs(self):
        return len(self.ngrams(self.letters(list),2))

def pair_probability(self):
{pair : freqency / self.sum_pairs() for (pair, freqency) in self.pairs_freqency().iteritems()}

def pairwise(self, sequence):
    x,y = tee(sequence)
    next(y)
    return zip(x,y)
```

But when I try to print:

```
print pairs_freqency()
```

I get this error:

**Updated

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 281, in <module>
    print pairs(string, text)
  File "...", line 46, in get_pairs
    return filter(re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text)).match, frozenset(self.text))
  File "...", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "...", line 232, in _compile
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can someone help me as fast as possible.
Thanks.

Comment: You're certainly making it as hard as possible for anybody to really help you (much less "as fast as possible") by revealing your code in dribs and drabs and always partially.  Now we know that `pairwise` returns a list (that's what `zip` returns in Python 2) and you're trying to `re.compile` a list, which is not possible, though the error *should* be `TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern`.  What are you trying to accomplish by "re.compiling a list", if that was possible -- what re do you expect (mistakenly) from such a compile?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Counter` needs as its argument an iterable each of whose items is **hashable** (==can be a key into a `dict`).  The items in you cases are **lists**, which are not hashable (because they're mutable).  Fix: use tuples instead, specifically in your `pairs` method -- instead of

```
    return filter(re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text)).match, list(self.text))
```

use

```
    return filter(re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text)).match, tuple(self.text))
```

Comment: @Borgmester I see the error is actually in `re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text))` -- it doesn't actually get to the point where my (still-needed) fix will help.  So show us what `self.pairwise(self.txt)` returns (and the code for that `pairwise`), which you have not shown so far (do so editing your Q, it's not readable in comments).

Comment: @Borgmester, if `self.text` was a string, the error from `re.compile` would be `TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern`.  So what **is** `self.text` instead?  In any case `pairwise` returns a `zip` result (a list, as it happens, but a tuple would be no better) and that can **never** be the right type of argument for `re.compile`.  So what **is** self.text, and what did you _think_ `re.compile`ing that zip would do?!

Answer (score 4):

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Error` happens when you try to use a `list` as key in a `dict` (or member of `set` or `frozenset`). The standard way to solve this issue is to cast a `list` to `tuple`, for example:

```
In [4]: my_dict = {[2,3,4] : 'a'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cda6d34218c4> in <module>()
----> 1 my_dict = {[2,3,4] : 'a'}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

In [5]: my_dict = {tuple([2,3,4]) : 'a'}
In [6]: my_dict
Out[6]: {(2, 3, 4): 'a'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting any list `lst` to `frozenset(lst)`.

Comment: I don't understand that, can u give me an example?

Comment: I can't follow your traceback but if you can find the list put `frozenset()` around it.

Comment: Isn't a `tuple` a better hashable replacement for a `list` than a `frozenset`?

Comment: Perhaps, it is simply a preference.

Comment: `return filter(re.compile(self.pairwise(self.text)).match, frozenset(self.text))`